# How to add button in JTabbedPane background?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I want to add button in my JTabbedPane background like Google Chrome so that every time I can add new tabs by clicking it.

[image]

How can I do it? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**: I have taken an undecorated JFrame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the [`JTabbedPane.setTabComponentAt( int index, Component component )`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#setTabComponentAt-int-java.awt.Component-) method. This method allows you to set the component with which to render the title.

Description from documentation:

> Sets the component that is responsible for rendering the title for the specified tab. A null value means JTabbedPane will render the title and/or icon for the specified tab. A non-null value means the component will render the title and JTabbedPane will not render the title and/or icon.
>
> Note: The component must not be one that the developer has already added to the tabbed pane.

---

What you can do:

- Create the `JTabbedPane`
- Add a new tab to it, its intended function like the chrome "add tab page"
- Set the title component of that tab to a button (style it appropriately)
- When that button is clicked, add a new tab right before the button tab and show the newly added tab

Answer (score 1):

This code will create only one tab and button to it.

```
class Test extends JFrame
{
 JTabbedPane jtab;
 JButton but;
 JPanel panel;

  Test()
 {
     super("JTabbedPane");
     jtab=new JTabbedPane();
     but=new Button("Click");
     panel=new JPanel();
     panel.add(but);

     jtab.add("Tab",panel);

     add(jtab);

     setVisible(true);
     setSize(400,400);
  }

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    new Test();
 }
}
```